# Local & Prod Settings.py in Django

Tags: django

I've implemented the normal way to do `local` and `prod` with two `settings.py` files and an `__init__.py`:

```
from .base import *

from .production import *

try:
    from .local import *
except:
    pass
```

The problem is that in some of my `views.py` files, there is also **specific functionality depending on `local` or `prod`**, for example integrating `django axes` in `prod`.

How can I check if I use the local or prod settings file in my `views.py` files? Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One common option is to check the `DEBUG` flag in your setting file as a means of differentiating between production and local/dev work.

```
from django.conf import settings

if settings.DEBUG:
    print('This is in debug mode')
```

Comment: This makes sense! Is there a way to do this in my templates as well? Or do I have to pass in DEBUG through context? Thanks!!

Comment: You could pass it in through context if you wanted and then use the if template tags in your template files https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/#if

Comment: Makes sense. Thank you so much for your response!! Will accept the answer in one minute.